# Unzipping of downloaded .gz file fails due to UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, gzip

Trying to download a .gz file, unzip it to memory and then read line by line of the  unzipped content.

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url)
print(r.headers)

with gzip.open(r.content, 'rb') as f:
    '''Reading line by line'''
```

Now the headers look like this:

> {'Date': 'Fri, 23 Aug 2019 07:19:28 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache',
>   'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Frame-Options': 'sameorigin',
>   'Referrer-Policy': 'no-referrer', 'X-Xss-Protection': '1',
>   'Last-Modified': 'Sat, 23 Jun 2018 09:21:46 GMT', 'ETag':
>   '"8be6ca-56f4bad760d07"', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Length':
>   '9168586', 'X-Clacks-Overhead': 'GNU Terry Pratchett',
>   'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=120', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5,
>   max=100', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Content-Type':
>   'application/x-gzip'}

The error I get seems to be an encoding error, but requests has `r.content` in UTF-8 already I suppose and `gzip.open()` wants UTF-8, so I don't get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position
>   1: invalid start byte

There are similar questions on SO, which didn't help me.

Comment: could you try with `gzip.open(r.content, 'rb', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: This gives me `ValueError: Argument 'encoding' not supported in binary mode`.

Comment: Ah yeah, and in text mode? It is said [to be supported too](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/gzip.html#gzip.open): `r` instead of `rb`

Comment: With `gzip.open(r.content, 'r', encoding='utf-8')` it still says `ValueError: Argument 'encoding' not supported in binary mode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [[Python-Requests.2]: Developer Interface - class requests.Response.**content**](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.content) (**emphasis** is mine):

> **Content** of the response, in bytes.

On the other hand, [[Python 3.Docs]: gzip.**open**(*filename, mode='rb', compresslevel=9, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open):

> The *filename* argument can be an actual filename (a [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) or [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object), or an existing file object to read from or write to.

To get past this issue, you shouldn't pass `r.content` to `gzip.open`, but either:

- Wrap it by a `io.BytesIO` like object, and pass that to `gzip.open`:

  ```py
  with gzip.open(io.BytesIO(fc)) as f:
      # Your original code (that reads line by line)
  ```
- Pass it to `gzip.decompress`:

  ```py
  extracted = gzip.decompress(r.content)
  for line in extracted.split(b"\n"):
      # Process each line
      print(line.decode())
  ```

  or (combining with previous bullet)

  ```py
  with io.BytesIO(gzip.decompress(r.content)) as f:
      # Your original code (that reads line by line)
  ```
- Save it into a file, and pass its name to `gzip.open` (note that this is very slow, and can introduce other potential issues, as pointed out by @Aran-Fey):

  ```py
  file_name = "content.gzip"
  with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
      f.write(r.content)
  with gzip.open(r.content, 'rb') as f:
      # Your original code (that reads line by line)
  os.unlink(file_name)
  ```

Comment: Good answer, except for the solution that writes the data to disk - that's slow *and* a lot of things can go wrong. The other 2 solutions are much better.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Thanks for the hint (and edit :) ), updated.